# Property 'signInUserSession' does not exist on type 'AmplifyUser' but exists at runtime

Tags: reactjs, authentication, aws-amplify

I'm using the `useAuthenticator` hook from AWS Amplify and I'm confused why certain properties do not exist at compile time. I get the error  `Property 'signInUserSession' does not exist on type 'AmplifyUser'`. However, when setting a debugger, I get to see that it does exist at runtime.

```
import { useAuthenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
const { route, user } = useAuthenticator((context) => [context.route, context.user]);
const userGroup = user.signInUserSession.getIdToken.payload['cognito:groups'];
// no property 'signInUserSession' 

const userGroup = user.getSignInUserSession()?.getIdToken.payload['cognito:groups'];
// no property 'payload' on CognitoIdToken
```

The console with the debugger.

```
$ user.signInUserSession.idToken.payload['cognito:groups']
> ['tutors']

// also works in console
$ user.getSignInUserSession().idToken.payload['cognito:groups']
> ['tutors']
```

The only typescript suggestion is to use `user.getSignInUserSession()` method, but that doesn't work. Why is there confusion with the type definitions about what is there and what isn't?

Answer (score 1):

> The only typescript suggestion is to use user.getSignInUserSession() method, but that doesn't work.

Theres a [related Github issue open here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/10142) and the author had also posted their solution:
[image]
...which worked for me when I ran into a similar issue.

> Why is there confusion with the type definitions about what is there and what isn't?

Didn't look too much into why, but if you scroll down on the linked issue there is [an RFC](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/11113) published last month to make improvements on Amplify JS Typescript.